# Restricting a basis of a vector space $V$ in order to form a basis of a subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We know as a trivial result of Linear Algebra, that given a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ with $\dim V=n$ and $W\subset V$ a subspace of $V$ with $\dim W=k$, $k<n$ we can always extend a basis of $W$ in order to form a basis of $V$ (by associating $n-k$ linearly independent elements to the given basis).

Is the inverse true? And if not, then

> Under which conditions can we constraint a basis of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ in order to create a basis of a subspace of $V$?

If for example we consider $\Bbb{R^n}$ and a basis $$B_n=[(1,0,0, \cdots)_1,(0,1,0,\cdots)_2, \cdots (0, \cdots,0,1)_n]$$ and let $\Bbb{R^k}$ with $k<n$ be a subspace of $\Bbb{R^n}$ , it is easy to see that we can constraint $[(1,0,0, \cdots)_1,(0,1,0,\cdots)_2, \cdots (0, \cdots,0,1)_n]$ to a basis of $\Bbb{R^k}$ by chosing the appropriate $k$ vectors from $B_n$. 

Can we produce a counterexample where such a construction is not possible?

Comment: For example, consider $W=\{ (t,t): t\in \Bbb R\} \subset \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you! Simple counterexample that gets the job done.

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem correctly. If $B=\{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, and $k_1,\dotsc,k_m$ are distinct integers chosen from $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ and $m<n$, then $\{e_{k_1},\dotsc,e_{k_m}\}$ *is* a basis for some subspace.(Linearly independent vectors cannot suddenly become linearly dependent when you throw some away.) On the other hand, given a proper vector subspace $W$ of $V$, we have no reason to expect that $B\cap W\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: @SamM They will be linearly independent but that does not mean that they produce the subspace. Check Omnomnomnom's counterexample and consider a basis of $\Bbb{R^2}$, i.e$(1,0),(0,1)$

Comment: You have misunderstood what I have written. If I take some subset $B'$ of a basis $B$ for $V$ and let $W$ be the linear span of $B'$, then $B'$ is a basis for $W$ (trivially). I followed that with the situation given in the example of @Omnomnomnom. The vector space $W$ generated by $(1,1)$ in $\mathbb {R}^2$ does not even contain the vectors $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, so they cannot possibly be a basis. My comment was that the question, as written in the question, is a little ambiguous as it is currently written.

Comment: @SamM I beg to difer: the question seems to me pretty clear and, in fact, it is a standard question in many first years quizzes and exams I've seen.

Comment: As it is written, it could be read: under what conditions does restricting a basis for a vector space $V$ give a basis for a subspace of $V$. To which the answer is always. Alternatively it could be read: Given a vector space $V$, a basis $B$ for $V$, and a subspace $W$ of $V$, under what conditions on $W$ does some subset $B'$ of $B$ form a basis for $W$. Which, as we have seen, is only in a few cases.

Comment: @SamM "under what conditions does restricting a basis for a vector space VV give a basis for a subspace of V.." But the answer is vare rarely-described in the accepted answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most general case, almost never. For example, the standard (or canonical) basis of $\;\Bbb R^2_{\Bbb R}\;$ , $\;\{\,(1,0),\,(0,1)\,\}\;$ cannot be restricted to a basis of no (proper) subspace whatsoever except the two obvious one: the lines (one-dimensional) $\;y=0\,,\,x=0\;$.

Your example about $\;\Bbb R^k\;$ is not so accurate, as you are choosing a very, very special, particular embedding of $\;\Bbb R^k\;$ into $\;\Bbb R^m\;$ . Take instead

$$\Bbb R^k\cong\,\text{Span}\,\left\{\,(1,1,0,...0), (0,1,0,...,)\,,\,\ldots, (0,0,..,\overbrace{1}^{k},0,...,0)\,\right\}$$

and then you have no restriction of the standard basis to a basis of the above subspace.

Comment: Thank you! This was quite enlightening. Coupled with Omnomnomnom's counterexample I understand why it fails in the general case. PS It would still be of interest I guess to define these exceptions ("almost never") if they are so rare, right?

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Thank you. The exceptions are really "exceptional": just the span of all the subsets of the basis you chose that yield different subspaces, and that's all. This is very restrictive, in my opinion.

Comment: I am quite confused by what you claim above. The first $k$ standard basis vectors for $\mathbb R^m$ are certainly contained within the linear span of $(1,1,0,\dotsc,0),(0,1,0,\dotsc,0),\dotsc, (0,\dotsc,1,0,\dotsc,0)$ that you have above. (For instance, take $(1,1,0,\dots)-(0,1,0,\dots)$.) So the first $k$ vectors from the standard basis for $\mathbb R^m$ do form a basis for the subspace you list.

Comment: @SamM Thank you. **Any** vector is contained in the span of *any* basis in a vector space. That follows trivially from the very definition. In this case, it seems to me the asker wanted that some subset of some basis, in this case the standard one, could be chosen that'd span a given subspace. In my example, there is **no** subset of the standard basis that is a basis of the given subspace isomorphic with $\;\Bbb R^k$

Comment: @Joanpemo The first $k$ vectors from the standard basis *do* span the subspace you defined, hence my confusion. What is true is that if you extend the basis that you specify $\{e_1+e_2,e_2,\dotsc,e_k\}$ above by adding the vectors $e_{k+1},\dotsc,e_n$, then you don't recover the standard basis. But that is not to say that the vectors $e_1,\dotsc,e_k$ do not span the subspace.

Comment: @SamM I think I understand now better what's the problem. Thank you, I agree that some confusion can pop up here.

Comment: Here is a genuine counterexample. Let $e_k$ denote the vector with $1$ in the $k$-th position and $0$ elsewhere (in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Fix $k<n$. Take $f_1=e_1+e_2$, $f_j=e_{j+1}$ for $j=1,\dotsc,k-1$. Then the linear span $W$ of $f_1,\dotsc,f_{k-1}$ is linearly isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k-1}$, does not contain $e_1$ or $e_2$ but does contain an element in the span of $e_1$ and $e_2$. Thus no subset of $\{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$ can be a basis for $W$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that given a basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$ for $V$ and a subspace $W$ with basis $\{w_1, \ldots, w_k \}$, the basis $\{w_1, \ldots, w_k\}$ can be extended to a basis for $V$, but not necessarily to the same basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ that we had before.